# Get the url of requesting domain or service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a module that is to be accessed by a third party solution. There would be an interchange of data on my side of the application. I need to know the requester's domain name so as to make sure that the data/request originated from the right source.

If someone is accessing www://abc.com/A1/A2 (my application) from www://xyz.com/Y1 then I need to get "xyz.com" to verify it's source. I've created a custom attribute over my action A2, which would be screening values posted from xyz.com. Here I need to verify the domain name before i perform any other operations.

The technology I'm using is MVC 4 C#.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`

I think [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/11/A_Gotcha_Identifying_the_Users_IP_Address.aspx/) would be helpful for you.